# Doubts about ParquetFileReader.getFilteredRecordCount() method

Tags: java, parquet

I'm trying to understand how this method works. In my understanding this method should return the number of records that match the filter criteria specified in the creation of the reader, but it doesn't work. It always returns the same value, that is exactly the number of records the file has.

I tried with this code:

```java
try (var reader = new ParquetFileReader(new FileSystemInputFile(file),
    ParquetReadOptions.builder().withRecordFilter(filter).build())) {
   var count = reader.getFilteredRecordCount();
   System.out.println(count);
}
```

But no matter what I put in the filter, it always return the total record count.

Answer (score 0):

The filter criteria may not be specified correctly: Make sure that the filter criteria you're using is valid and matches the data types and values in the file.

The filter criteria may not be compatible with the data type of the column being filtered: Ensure that the data type of the column you're filtering on matches the data type expected by the filter.

There may be a bug in the implementation of the filter or in the ParquetFileReader class itself: Check the documentation and known issues for the Parquet library you're using, and try updating to the latest version of the library.

To further diagnose the issue, you can try debugging the code and examining the values of the filter criteria and the data being filtered on. You may also want to consider reaching out to the Parquet library community or support team for assistance.